# When trying to multiply with a method I get this output ஸ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby Noob here - Trying to make a very simple appointment booking form that outputs a confirmation and the amount of time the appointment will take.  I've gotten the concatenation working on the output but I keep getting this character (ஸ) where the amount of time should be.  Below is my ruby document and the output.

```
print "Whats your name?"
    name = gets.to_s
print "What is the address for your listing?"
    appointment_address = gets
print "Square footage?"
    sq_ft = gets.to_i
print "listing price"
    listing_price = gets

# PHOTOGRAPHERS

def tps
    tps = 3.to_i
end

def ryan(sq_ft,tps)
    p sq_ft.to_i * tps.to_i
end

appointment_confirmation = 'Hey, '<< name.to_s.strip << '! Your appointment at ' << appointment_address.to_s.strip << ' will take us about ' << sq_ft*tps << ' to complete.'

p appointment_confirmation.strip
```

---

Output:

Hey, Alex! Your appointment at 102 Alex will take us about ஸ to complete.

Comment: `"What is " << 3000 #=>  "What is ஸ"`.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an integer to a string, the integer is converted into its corresponding character code. Cast your integer to a string:

```
' will take us about ' << (sq_ft*tps).to_s << ' to com ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending an integer to a string. The integer is treated as character code.

The following prints our the letters A-Z because 65 is the code of "A" and 90 the code of "Z".

```
s = ""
(65..90).each do |ascii_code|
  s << ascii_code
end
puts s
```

Either convert the amount to a string or (and this is my preferred way) use string interpolation:

```
"Hey, #{name} the duration is #{sq_ft*tps}"
```

Where `#{}` can be used to interpolate ruby values into a string. This only works with double quoted strings.

Comment: Perfect thank you!  This is much easier than what I was doing.

Comment: @Mag_enthzd if one of the Answers helped you, please take some time to accept it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for details.